# Upgrade SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition to SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, upgrade

I have several x64 SQL 2012 Developer servers with SP2 and CU4/CU5. In your experience, with this SP/CU mix, is the upgrade to 2014 Developer supported ? I can only find information on the supported path from 2012 SP1 to 2014.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Microsoft BOL '[Supported Version and Edition Upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)'

> SQL Server 2014 supports upgrade from the following versions of SQL
>   Server:
>   • SQL Server 2005 SP4 or later
>   • SQL Server 2008 SP3 or later
>   • SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 or later
>   • SQL Server 2012 SP1 or later

So, as you have 'later' than 2012 SP1, then answer is **yes**.

The actual 'Upgrades from Earlier Versions to SQL Server 2014' section of the linked article just looks like it is out of date and requires addition of 2012 SP2.

Comment: Yes, it's not that clear if you look at all the sections in the MSDN article, and there's no mention of CU. Tested, it works, even installed CU5 on one server before the upgrade, no issues.

Comment: You should consider [CU6](http://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3031047) if you are using clustered columnstore with DBCC CHECKDB due to the memory leak detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3034615).